# Android O - how it effects GeoFencing

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

This is from the Android 8 behaviour changes docs:

> **These changes affect the following APIs:**  Fused Location Provider (FLP)  **Geofencing**  GNSS Measurements  Location Manager  Wi-Fi Manager

So it is clear that geo fencing is affected however after a few sentences they say:

> Consider using the Fused Location Provider (FLP) or geofencing to
>   handle the use cases that depend on the user's current location.

(reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#atap)

Anyone have more information about how geo fencing behavior is affected on Android 8?